# Query, SQL, Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby, performance, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working a project and encountered a problem regarding writing the best query for the problem.

I will start presenting the problem and the solution I found.
We have the following ERD structure:
[image]

A Player has many Scores, and a Score has many Handicap Results.
We have a many to many relationship between Handicap and League.

In my app at some point I run a calculation formula that takes all players from a Customer or League and for each score of the player we create a handicap result corresponding to he Handicaps that the Club / League has.

HandicapResults: value, score_id, handicap_id

Handicaps: game_type(string), league_ids (association between the handicap and leagues)

Score: league_id, player_id, game_type(string), play_at (date), round_id (integer)

On the customers#show action I want to display for all handicaps and players the result.

The result is the LAST SCORE PLAYED SORTED BY ROUND_ID DESC AND PLAY_AT DESC. From this score we the the handicap_result corresponding to customer handicaps.

The solution I found for one player would be:

[image]

The only problem is that this will do 1 select for all players displayed in the view. I would want to write a select that would return the values for a collection of players (player_ids).

At the moment the sql returns the handicap_result corresponding to the last score played (sorted_by round_id desc and play_at desc) where score.league_id included in handicap.league_ids and score.game_type = handicap.game_type.

I would want to created a method that can have as parameters player_ids, handicaps, ... all informations required for the query.

That returns the following:

Ex:

```
player_ids: [1, 2, 3]
handicaps: [handicap_1, handicap_2]
# and return something like:
{
   #player_id 1: { handicap_1.id: value, handicap_2.id: value }
   .........
   #player_id 5: { handicap_1.id: value, handicap_2.id: value }
}

# the value is the handicap_result where handicap_result.handicap_id == handicap_1.id / handicap_2.id and for the corresponding score
```

Hopefully I described the problem correctly and people can understand me. I really wish that someone can help me into writing the query that runes 1 time and returns the values for a given collection of players.

Thank you and have a nice day!